AWS SES email taking long time to receive on gmail and verification link showing suspicious
I have integrate aws SES in my server. I am facing some issue. When I send mail from my server to user (gmail) it taking long time to receive on user mail address. It takes about 5-6 minutes average(some mail takes more then 10 min)
I have already verify the domain and email address both in SES console.
I have investigated, if I have sent mail at 2:20am it will reach on the mail box 2:25am but there will show 5 minute ago. Mean 2:20am but I have received it at 2:25am.
How to solve this problem?
I have got also an other problem.
problem 2:
When I am sending link for verification email and user try to click on the link, it is showing:
Suspicious link
This link opens a site that might be harmful.
Hide details ▲
The reputation of j03i68cf.r.ap-southeast-2.awstrack.me is unknown. Are you sure you want to continue?
My domain has no problem. It has ssl certificate and my domain reputation also good.(This is not my domain j03i68cf.r.ap-southeast-2.awstrack.me this link redirect to my main link).
How to solve it?

You need to make sure you have DKIM as well as DMARC configured correctly for your SES domain.
For the awstrack.me domain issue, you need to follow the documentation to enable the use of your custom domain for click tracking links.
